# Difference between int a,b = 0 and int a=0, int b = 0

Tags: c#, variables

Is there a difference between the following two code blocks?

```
int a, b, c  = 0;
```

and

```
int a = 0; int b = 0; int c = 0;
```

Is that exactly the same or is there some difference?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the `= 0` case or do you care about other cases as well?

Comment: Specifically for the = 0

Comment: It would be the same if you had `int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first code block, `int a, b, c  = 0;`, you are not initializing the primitive types. You cannot use a and b until it is assigned something, event if `a = default(int)` or just `a = 0`. Until first assignment, you'll get a compilation error that the variable must be assigned before first use.

Now if you are comparing `int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0` and `int a = 0; int b = 0; int  c = 0;`, those are identical. The IL for both of those statements are the same:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  stloc.2     // c
```

There is also no difference with assigning to the `default` value instead of 0 (ie: `int a = default(int);`).

Comment: You didn't cover the class field initialization rules.

Comment: And OP is asking about initialization of primitive type.

Comment: He never said where is this code block located. It behaves differently in method code block and class declaration.

Comment: Absolutely agree on the difference between the two. The context is definitely subjective.

Answer (score 2):

No. this is not the same by default.

```
public void AMethod()
{
    int a;
}
```

doesn't initialize your variable, this is not a class field, and you can't use this variable until it got it's value in this method.

If you have a class definition like this:

```
class A
{
    int a;
}
```

Then, during the creation of an `A` object, `a` field will be initialized internally with `default(int)` value, which is `0`.

Comment: Of course, `int`s [default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) is 0

Comment: Or, to make this apply the same to variables and fields - the first version doesn't assign anything to `a` and `b`, just `c`.

Comment: It does initialize, but VS might give you a compile warning that there's a variable that is not assigned a value.

Comment: @Sayse It will leave the variable uninitialized. Defaults don't matter for variables, just fields.

Comment: @Luaan you're wrong. Read the spec.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Not true. If you try to use the variable before assigning a value, the code will not compile.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Use the compiler. It doesn't compile. You're reading the spec wrong :)

Comment: Any reasons for downvote?

Comment: @Luaan - Sure, still think it is worth noting :)

Comment: @Luaan You are correct.  You get a warning at first, but compiling does indeed show it also as a compile error.  I guess I've never tried compiling with unused variables (in C# at least).

Comment: @Sayse Sure. Reading through blogs of guys like Mark Seeman, it seems that there was actually a lot of thought put into evading any default values at all, having `null` unavailable by default etc., but it's almost impossible in C#. It would be really handy for avoiding a lot of issues, but there's no way .NET's memory management could guarantee object initialization etc. in those cases. We've had a lot of discussions about this, and it's way more complicated than it seems on the surface :D

Comment: @Luaan `null` isn't applicable for the `int`

Comment: @oscilatingcretin It's a great sanity check. I make sure to only assign values to variables when it actually makes sense - if there's a branch of code which skips this and I read the value later, the compiler tells me about my mistake - much faster than waiting for runtime errors :)

Comment: @VMAtm I'm not saying it is :)